# / (slash) in preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

I have this section **some/aaa/9321/something** from which I want to extract only **9321**. "something" always differs, "aaa" is alyways static. So, I used:

```
$text = "something/aaa/9321/something";
$first = 'aaa/';
$after = '/';
preg_match("/$first(.*)$after/s",$text,$result);
echo $result;
```

But isn't working. Can somebody please tell me what I need to use?
I've tried this too:

```
$text = "something/aaa/9321/something";
$first = 'aaa';
preg_match("|$first(.*)|",$text,$result);
echo substr($result['1'], 1, 4);
```

But between **aaa** and **something** not always 4 characters.

Sorry for bad english. Thanks!

Comment: *"But isn't working."*. You need to enable error logging, follow the error log, start to learn about the messages presented to you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)

Comment: Like `$after = '\/';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always [preg_quote](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) strings when you want them to be taken literally in a regular expression:

```
$text = 'something/aaa/9321/something';
$first = preg_quote('aaa/', '/');
$after = preg_quote('/', '/');
preg_match("/$first(.*)$after/s",$text,$result);
echo $result[1]; // '9321'
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/1Xcc0a)

The problem was caused by the fact that `/` is the delimiter in your regex. You could have also solved this problem by using a different delimiter, such as `~`, however, you would just run into the same problem as soon as your string had a `~` or any other character with a special meaning like `.`, or `?`. By using preg_quote, you won't run into this problem again.

Comment: `preg_quote` I liked this function +1

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried escaping the `/`? 
Instead of

```
$first = 'aaa/';
$after = '/';
```

try

```
$first = 'aaa\/';
$after = '\/';
```